# How to set and retrieve unique ID for dynamically added Spinner inside ListView row in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner

I've tried so many things and have spent countless hours on this issue without any luck.

What I have is a `ListView` inside a fragment.  The `ListView` starts off empty, but when a button is clicked in the parent `Fragment`, a row is generated in the `ListView` containing both a `TextView`(generated via user input) and a `Spinner`.  The `Spinner` added to each row is identical using the same set of pre-built data.  The row is then sorted alphabetically based on the name fed into the `TextView`. The rows in the `ListView` can also be deleted with the click of other set parameters from the parent `Fragment`.

All of this works perfectly fine.

What I need to do is to uniquely identify each spinner object that is added so that the user can save and recall the positional value of each spinner object that is associated with each name within the containing row of the `ListView`.

What I have been able to do is, as the list grows, point to the very first spinner object, the very last spinner object, and the spinner object that last had an item selected, but I cannot figure out how to point to each specific spinner object in the row.

P.S. I am able to point to each `TextView` object being that they are names that have been added to an `ArrayList`.

Working with arrays generally works well for me, but while I know how to store spinner position values into an array so that I can have them retrieved for specific spinners, I can't figure out how to store them for multiples of essentially the same spinner...  I feel I need to create an `ArrayList` of Spinners containing each spinner as it's added, and while I know how to access the positional value of the spinner, I don't know how to access the positional value of each spinner contained within an array of spinners, if that makes sense.

I've tried `setId` and `setTag` [using position] for each spinner as it's generated, but with no luck.  What seems to happen is the Id and Tag only stick to the last spinner added.

I've also tried using `Intent` but with no such luck.  The app crashes every time I try passing it out of the child `Fragment`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's some code for the problem points:

- parent fragment -

```java
    charSav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            relationsListArray.add(charNameString);
            if (frag2_3.relationsSpinner != null && frag2_3.currentRowSpinner != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < frag2_3.relationsListView.getCount(); i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "row " +
// outputs outputs name displayed in each textview within each row
                    relationsListView.getItemAtPosition(i) + "\nT. " +
// outputs top most spinner item selected
                    currentRowSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\nB. " +
// outputs bottom most spinner item selected
                    relationsSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\nL. " +
// outputs the last spinner item selected whether it be first, last, or somewhere in the middle
                    relationsItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

- child fragment containing adapter class -

```java
    public class RelationsListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        public RelationsListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            relationsListArray = objects;
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() { return relationsListArray.size(); }
        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) { return relationsListArray.get(position); }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) { String item = getItem(position); return mIdMap.get(item); }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_spinner_row, null);
            }
        // Spinner Adapter
            adapterRelationsSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.preStoryPlanRelations)){
                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position){
                    if(position == 0) { return false; }
                    else { return true; }
                }
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    if (position == 0) {
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#424242"));
                    }
                    tv.setTextSize(12);
                    tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
                    return view;
                }
                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    if (position == 0) {
                        tv.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC));
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#424242"));
                        tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                    }
                    else {
                        tv.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            };
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_textview);
            tv.setText(relationsListArray.get(position));
            relationsSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_spinner);
            relationsSpinner.setAdapter(adapterRelationsSpinner);
            relationsSpinner.setTag(R.id.row_item_spinner+position);
            relationsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    selectedRowView = (ViewGroup) relationsListView;
                    currentRowSpinner = (Spinner) selectedRowView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_spinner);
                    relationsItem = currentRowSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    relationsRowPosition = relationsListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
```